# Mongoose pre middleware with findByIdAndDelete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im following a course on Udemy for Node js. There mongoose pre middleware is used with remove like this.

```
ReviewSchema.pre('remove', function() {
  // code goes here
});
```

But my implementation is different and I want to use findByIdAndDelete. This is my code.

```
ReviewSchema.pre('findByIdAndDelete', function() {
  // code goes here
});
```

But this one doesn't trigger. I tried to console.log inside this, but it doesn't trigger. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems no middleware for `findByIdAndDelete`.

But since `findByIdAndDelete` triggers the `findOneAndDelete`, you can take advantage of this.

So your ReviewSchema must be updated like this:

```
ReviewSchema.pre("findOneAndDelete", function() {
  console.log("called!!!");
});
```

Also it is a good idea to include next() so that it does not stop the rest of the code in your middleware function from executing.

```
ReviewSchema.pre("findOneAndDelete", function(next) {
  console.log("called!!!");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that middleware doesn't exists. Take a look at the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html).

But, if you go to `findByIdAndDelete`'s [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndDelete) then you will see that it triggers the following middleware:

- `findOneAndDelete`

So, instead of `ReviewSchema.pre('findByIdAndDelete', ...)` try `ReviewSchema.pre('findOneAndDelete', ...)`.